Why does "Unable to install breakpoint due to missing line number attributes" happen when the breakpoints still work?
When adding @Slf4j, why does Eclipse throw an error about breakpoints that were previously were and are(?) working?
### Java Breakpoint 

Unable to install breakpoints in xxx.xxx...$$EnhancerBySpringxxx due to missing line number attributes. Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes.

Reason: 
Absent Line Number Information 
[ ] Don't tell me again 
[OK]

This project only fails when I add the Slf4j annotation. This project works fine before I add this atop the main class. But adding Slf4j seems necessary to get AspectJ to report out logging.
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({xxx.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { /* ... */ } )
// Problem adding this SLF4J here
@Slf4j
public class MainApp {}

I have a POC (Proof-Of-Concept) that has this working fine within a Spring Boot setup as well.
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);
    // ... 
    @Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
    public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Breakpoint On Logging Here ... 
        logger.info(joinPoint.getSignature() + " executed in " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
        return proceed;
    }
    // ...
}

This project cannot be easily rebuilt, moved, or redone. Otherwise, this post wouldn't have been made. And, this seems like a common situation a lot of professional and career developers can find themselves in and understand.
How can this Eclipse-Debugger runtime-error actually and realistically be fixed?
I've tried:

Restarting Eclipse and the OS
Removing and readding the breakpoints
Rebuilding the project  mvn clean compile and/or install
Reassigning the JDK, Maven, and their configurations
Rerunning mvn clean compile and/or install
Proof-testing the example works and that I understand the basics of the concepts
Undoing-Redoing the code change in-case something was hanging or not check-triggering correctly

I'm not looking for help ignoring, hiding, or suppressing this issue.
I have seen those other answers listed on SO. Many questions on this are old and may not apply to the current Eclipse, Java, or Spring.
I'm looking to fix this issue and understand what's going on to cause this, not ignore the problem and hope this doesn't affect me.
How come the Project Lombok lombock.extern.slf4j annotation type can fail Eclipse breakpoints in a Spring Boot application?

The .class files must contain line number information, otherwise the Java VM does not know which code is referenced by the given line, preventing setting a breakpoint. The code where you set the breakpoint needs re-compiled with the right options.

Could the message about the *$$EnhancerBySpringxxx classes already be telling you exactly what's happening (how sure are you that the enhancement includes writing out the proper line information to the final .class file)? Does the debugger actually stop on the line?

@nitind No, the debugger doesn't seem to stop on the lines.
